# Fire action in DialogFragment after button has been clicked in other DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I guess its a stupid question but I am new to Android and I still have problems understanding communication between fragments. What I want to do:

I have a `DialogFragmentA` that contains some methods and a `DialogFragmentB` that contains a `yesButton` and a `noButton`.

If the `yesButton` in the `DialogFragmentB` has been clicked I would like to dismiss the fragment and fire a specific action in `DialogFragmentA`.

How can a achieve that?

Comment: Is both fragments are dialog ?

Comment: Both are DialogFragments. So not a Dialog per se.

Answer (score 0):

If both fragments are dialog then you can do the following : 
Set dialogFragmentA as targetFragment for dialogFragmentB 
In dialogFragmentB use getTargetFragment to get dialogFragmentA. 
Then use that reference to call any method inside dialogFragmentA

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong, but this would mean that I still would have to call the method in the DialogFragmentB on a instance of DialogFragmentA, wright?

Comment: You will be calling a method on reference of dialogfragmentA which you get from calling getTargetFragment method

Answer (score 0):

use ViewPager inside your dialog box